Is there an API or way of operating related to the error of the thermostat in the 'Google Home app'?
Is there an API or way to work with the Google Home app related to thermostat error status?
I'm developing a Google Home app. The company app is already working and when the app controls the thermostat, it quickly reflects on Google Home. However, if there is a 'thermostat hardware' error, I don't know how to reflect it on the Google Home server or app. If there is a 'thermostat hardware error', I would like to inform the Google Home server and reflect it on the Google Home app. Is there a way to reflect it on the Google Home app when the error occurs?
Currently, I'm a 'intermediate server', so if the controller sends me data in any form from the server in front of me after the error, my API will send the data, status, etc. of the error controller to the Google Home server so that the 'Google Home Server' shows the controller error status to the 'Google Home App'. Is this a possible concept? Because of this, I ask the above question.
Do you have any documents or information related to this?
If only errorCode is omitted from the request below, it works normally. requestBody는 {"requestId":"test-240102001800FC3501","agentUserId":"testxxxxxx","payload":{"devices":{"states":{"test123456":{"thermostatMode":"heat","thermostatTemperatureSetpoint":44,"thermostatTemperatureAmbient":22,"online":true,"on":true,"errorCode":"deviceJammingDetected"}}}}}
Anyway I want to forward the error situation of the device to the Google server from 'my intermediate server'. Currently, I can, the "online" attribute is "false" and is treated in googlehomeapp as '오프라인(offline)' and exclamation points. (It's as similar to a device error as possible) But is there any other more sophisticated way?
Thank you for reading it.
